# Jekyll served page loses styles after modifications

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I have a static page in development with Jekyll, which runs okay after `bundle exec jekyll serve` although with the following warning:

```
Conflict: The following destination is shared by multiple files.
                    The written file may end up with unexpected contents.
                    /Users/username/Documents/Personal/RdM/_site/assets/main.css
                     - assets/main.scss
                     - /Users/username/Documents/Personal/RdM/assets/main.css
```

However, if I alter any of the `html` or `md` files and reload the browser, the page is broken, with all the styling missing. At that point, the only way to make it work again is `ctrl + c` to stop it and then run `serve` again.

Oddly enough, if what I modify is a stylesheet, the reload works as expected.

Comment: You'll have to understand what are those conflict about, it seems to be what your issue is about. What you can try to go further is to run jekyll with the `--verbose` switch in order to understand the underlaying issue.

Comment: Do you have this site in a public repo? It would help if we could see the code.